# How can I subset across multiple dataframes as a bounding box?

Tags: r

I have three dataframes.

a) Latitude:

```
20.08824    20.11288    20.13752    20.16218
20.09489    20.11954    20.14417    20.16882
20.11476    20.13941    20.16408    20.18874
20.12138    20.14604    20.17071    20.19536
```

b) Longitude:

```
-118.0981   -118.1052   -118.1123   -118.1194
-117.9931   -118.0002   -118.0072   -118.0143
-117.8092   -117.8162   -117.8232   -117.8302
-117.783    -117.7899   -117.7969   -117.8039
```

c) A variable, let's say windspeed

```
2   2   3   4
2   4   3   3
4   4   5   9
6   4   2   5
```

I have the Lat-Long coordinates for the edges of a bounding box for which I want to subset (c)

```
20.14417,-118.0002
20.14417,-118.0072
20.11954,-118.0002
20.11954,-118.0072

[Bounding Box][http://www.darrinward.com/lat-long/?id=634088]
```

I know how to subset columns within one dataframe, but I don't know how to do it across three dataframes. Could you please help.

Note: (a), (b) and (c) are Global datasets with exactly same dimensions. The data given here is only illustrative.

**ADDENDUM**

I have large Matrix, not dataframes, if it makes a difference.

Comment: I have changed it now. I did put a note that the data is for illustrative purposes only. It's a very large dataset and I didn't how to give a dput of it...Hope I explained properly..

Comment: you could just `dput(head(<data>))` to give a sample

Comment: I am not able to copy the entire dput(head()) as the size is too large....And droplevels doesn't work with matrices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would put everything into a data frame:

```
x<-data.frame(as.vector(lat),as.vector(long),as.vector(wind))
names(x)<-c("lat","long","wind")
dput(x)
```

giving:

```
 structure(list(lat = c(20.08824, 20.09489, 20.11476, 
20.12138, 20.11288, 20.11954, 20.13941, 20.14604, 20.13752, 20.14417, 
20.16408, 20.17071, 20.16218, 20.16882, 20.18874, 20.19536), 
    long = c(-118.0981, -117.9931, -117.8092, -117.783, 
    -118.1052, -118.0002, -117.8162, -117.7899, -118.1123, -118.0072, 
    -117.8232, -117.7969, -118.1194, -118.0143, -117.8302, -117.8039
    ), wind = c(2L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 
    5L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 9L, 5L)), .Names = c("lat", "long", 
"wind"), row.names = c("V11", "V12", "V13", "V14", "V21", 
"V22", "V23", "V24", "V31", "V32", "V33", "V34", "V41", "V42", 
"V43", "V44"), class = "data.frame")
```

Then it's a simple subset:

```
x[x$lat < 20.14417 & x$lat > 20.11954 & x$long < -118.0002 & x$long > -118.0072,]
```

Comment: Hi, how are you getting this structure? I am getting a 1536*3840 sized dataframe after the first line using my full dataset. I should get a 1536*3 dataframe, right?

Comment: I have added an addendum to my question. I mistook my data for a dataframe. I hope this doesn't change any operations...I don't know how it affects your answer.

Comment: in that case, use as.vector instead of unlist, and set names to make sure the subset still works

Comment: Err, quick question...How do I go back to three matrices from the subsetted dataframe at the end (in case I need it)?

Comment: you can use matrix(x$lat, nrow=x, ncol=y) as long as you know the size you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can subset across data frames by placing them into other other subsettable objects. Arrays and lists are used to hold them.

```
lst <- list(df1, df2, df3)
```

Then you can subset with functions. For example, the first column of each data frame:

```
lapply(lst, `[`, 1)
[[1]]
        V1
1 20.08824
2 20.09489
3 20.11476
4 20.12138

[[2]]
         V1
1 -118.0981
2 -117.9931
3 -117.8092
4 -117.7830

[[3]]
  V1
1  2
2  2
3  4
4  6
```

The same first column subset can be done with an array:

```
a <- simplify2array(c(df1, df2, df3))
dim(a) <- c(4,4,3)
a[,1,]
```

Comment: Can you elaborate how I can access these columns within a function? Thanks.

Comment: If you were getting the mean of the 3rd and 4th rows of all columns. For a single df you would use `colMeans(df[3:4,])`. So for the list use `lapply(lst, function(x) colMeans(x[3:4,]))`. Notice how it's the same function with an x placed where the df was originally. That x tells the func to do the same thing to each data frame as it would to one.